# Calendar functionality in MySql

Tags: mysql, calendar

I have the following MySql tables:

- Player table         - all player stuff
- Master_Task         - all tasks to choose from
- Player_Master_Task  - all tasks chosen for a player
- Player_Task_Plan    - When a player should do a task

Lets say a player has "Brush Teeth" in the Player_Master_Task.

That task needs to be done 3 times a day every day forever.  How do I persist that?  Basically I need calendar functionality for figuring out when a task should be performed.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Andrew

Comment: Check out 'Recurrence' under https://wiki.mozilla.org/Calendar:Sql_Calendar_Schema

Comment: I'm wondering if I should use a Calendar Server instead.  Anyone ever tried that?   https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/402382:the-five-best-open-source-calendar-servers-for-linux